# Get data from subscribe in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having difficulty getting data with subscribe in the constructor of an Ionic page, basically I need to do the subscribe to get a list and show to the user, but I get undefinied

In my constructor, I do this:

```
this.getUser(this.auth.currentUser().uid);
console.log(this.user);
```

My getUser():

```
getUser(uid) {
  const self = this;
  this.auth.getUserData(uid).subscribe(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    self.user = doc.data();
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
 });
};
```

But, when i call other function with button, i get the data:

```
userf(){
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

Obs: I use Firestore

Comment: Please post the error you are getting in the console.

Comment: The value of variable it is undefinied. It's not error

Answer (score 0):

The reason it gives you undefined is because your method “getUser” is async and when you call console.log the user value is not yet obtained.

So you should access user value inside your getUser method after it is received.

Now also you are trying to pass “this” into the getUser method with const. start using fat arrow functions which do not create their own scope (this):

```
getUser(uid) {
this.auth.getUserData(uid).subscribe((doc) => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    this.user = doc.data();
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
 });
};
```